# Frozen Resharper installator

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Im testing latest 5.0 night builds and starting from last build R# installatior has frozen.
I've tried everything
- install / uninstall
- add remove programs / repair
- install previous 4.5 version
- reinstall MSXML

Still same - it hangs at the last step of installation (Uninstalling from VS or Repairing VS)
Only way is killing process

What I also notoced is 3 msxml6 processes (2 system and 1 user)

So current situation is I have no "Resharper" menu in VS, its shortcuts dont work as well
Any advice ?

**EDIT**
- Rebooted few times
-I notoced that installers brings up devenv.exe  process. When I'm killing it installer successfully finishes (but still no Resharper in VS after...)

**EDIT 2**
Also Installer Windows Installer CleanUp (stil same...)

Comment: Have you tried to reboot the machine?

Comment: I;ve tried that several times actually. ughhh I'm desperated

Comment: How long shall I wait? I tried 20+ mins...

Comment: @TheSean: You can get nightly builds of the upcomming version 5.0. It's a pre-alpha-version, so there's no guarantee that is actually works. Link: http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+5.0+Nightly+Builds

Comment: Please note this is not only version 5 issue. I'm desperate to run any version (inc. last stable 4.5) but I cannot make it working with VS :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to RS Team finally found solution.

What helped:

```
devenv.exe /setup
devenv.exe /resetskippkgs
```

Maybe it will also help the others..